# fecth id and date from url as pros in react js

Tags: reactjs

This is the url I am getting. I want to access `customer` id and `date` from the url to function
but because this is not the default class, I am not able to do it and I need help.

http://localhost:3000/update?customer=66&date=2022-06-27&tab=user

```
const getData = (props) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    },
  };
  console.log(props.customer);
  return axios
    .get(
      "api?customer=" +this.props.customer+"&date=" + this.props.date,
      config
    )
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("error ocurred while fetching data", err);
      return null;
    });
};
```

full code i have given in sandbox for refernce
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-lalande-87jbpq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Do you want to retrieve `customer` and `date` values from the url?

Comment: yes i want to access the customer and date from url to the getData funtion pls have look at athe sandbox so u will have a undersnading of full code

Comment: Your sandbox link is not working properly. Some files are missing, so I'm just writing a answer below, have a look. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `react-router-dom` in your project, you might use `useLocation` hook

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'
const search = useLocation().search
console.log(URI.parseQuery(search))
```

Comment: React Hook "useLocation" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: i am getting this error

Comment: pls check the codesand box and tell me where to place the code

Comment: You may call it one line after `const SymptomTracker = (props) => {`, this should give you an object with all the query params, after that all you need to do is pass the data to the fn you'd like

Comment: i amgetting error  'URI' is not defined  @Breno

Comment: You may try even without URI.parseQuery

Comment: URI.parseQuery belongs to `urijs` lib, you will need it to parse the string into an object:

Comment: https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#static-parseQuery

Comment: i tryed without `URI.parseQuery`     my `console.log` is returning the following `?customer=22&date=2022-06-27&tab=diet`  i want  to sepratate  `22` & `2022-06-27`  & pass it to `getData`  funtion

Comment: Correct, `URI.parseQuery` will break this string into an object that you might use, check the documentation i posted above

Comment: Here is the npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/urijs

Comment: i instaled npm i urijs still i am getting error when i use   console.log(URI.parseQuery(search));

Comment: Are you importing the lib? `import URI from 'urijs'`

Comment: ok  i got the console.log {customer: '22', date: '2022-06-27', tab: 'diet'} like this how to pass date and customer to getData

Comment: can u help me with this i dont know how to pass custumer and date to getData